# Pandas: Combining two rows in the same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe containing NBA statistics for every game in the 2020 season. The problem is the date frame has 2 rows for every game. 1 row is the stats of one team the 2nd row is the stats for the opposing team. I want to combine these 2 rows. When I combining these I want to double the number of columns and add an "a" in front of all the column names to distinguish which stats are for the home team and which are for the away team.

For example a dataframe that looks like this

```
Team_ID     Abrv      Game_ID      Pts
123         LAL         111         101
124         NOP         111         110
125         NYK         112         98
126         WAS         112         116
```

would look like this afterwards:

```
Team_ID    Abrv       Game_ID      Pts   aTEAM_ID    aAbrv    aPTS
123        LAL        111          101   124         NOP      110
123        NYK        112          98    126         WAS      116
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `concat` then flatten the multi index

```
out = df.assign(key=df.groupby('Game_ID').cumcount().astype(str)).set_index(['Game_ID','key']).unstack('key').sort_index(level=1,axis=1)

out.columns=out.columns.map('_'.join)
out
Out[444]: 
        Abrv_0  Pts_0  Team_ID_0 Abrv_1  Pts_1  Team_ID_1
Game_ID                                                  
111        LAL    101        123    NOP    110        124
112        NYK     98        125    WAS    116        126
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I want the row to just contain one game ID

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
cumcount = df.groupby('Game_ID').cumcount()
renamer = {0: 'Home', 1: 'Away'}
df = df.set_index(['Game_ID', cumcount]).rename(renamer, level=1).unstack()

        Team_ID      Abrv       Pts     
           Away Home Away Home Away Home
Game_ID                                 
111         124  123  NOP  LAL  110  101
112         126  125  WAS  NYK  116   98
```

Slight variation

```
cumcount = df.groupby('Game_ID').cumcount()
renamer = {0: 'Home', 1: 'Away'}
df = df.set_index(['Game_ID', cumcount]).rename(renamer, level=1) \
  .unstack().swaplevel(0, 1, 1).sort_index(1)

        Away              Home             
        Abrv  Pts Team_ID Abrv  Pts Team_ID
Game_ID                                    
111      NOP  110     124  LAL  101     123
112      WAS  116     126  NYK   98     125
```

Comment: It doesn't appear that this changed my data frame. My data includes many more data points than Pts(ex. REBS, ASSISTS, etc) could this be the problem

Comment: assign it back to the dataframe `df = df.set_index(['Game_ID', cumcount]).rename(renamer, level=1).unstack().swaplevel(0, 1, 1).sort_index(1)`  No, it shouldn't be an issue.